# How to combine FOR VIEW and FOR REFERENCE?

Tags: soql, query

I'm writing a fluent query builder and have hit a snag. While looking at the documentation for the **[`FOR UPDATE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm)** clause, it has this snippet:

> Consider using the `FOR REFERENCE` clause with the `FOR VIEW` clause to update recent usage data for retrieved objects.

Okay, cool, so that answers my question of *if* the two clauses are supported in tandem. But it does not specify *how* to combine them. I can't seem to figure out the syntax. I tried all of the below queries with no luck.

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR VIEW FOR REFERENCE
```

**Error**

> unexpected token: REFERENCE

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR REFERENCE FOR VIEW
```

**Error**

> unexpected token: VIEW

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR VIEW, FOR REFERENCE
```

**Error**

> expecting right square bracket, found ','

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR VIEW, REFERENCE
```

**Error**

> expecting right square bracket, found ','

---

Also worth noting that either clause on its own can be combined with `FOR UPDATE`. At least...they work in `Execute Anonymous`. In the `Query Editor`, they still throw:

> Unknown error parsing query

**Valid Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR VIEW FOR UPDATE
```

**Valid Query**

```
SELECT Id FROM Account FOR REFERENCE FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: Setting up a **[chat room dedicated to this question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57907/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-larson-how-to-combine-for-view-and-for-referenc)**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [documentation of the syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm):

```
SELECT ***fieldList*** [subquery][...]
[TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression[...] elseExpression END][...]
FROM objectType[,...] 
    [USING SCOPE filterScope]
[WHERE conditionExpression]
[WITH [DATA CATEGORY] filteringExpression]
[GROUP BY {fieldGroupByList|ROLLUP (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)|CUBE (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)} 
    [HAVING havingConditionExpression] ] 
[ORDER BY fieldOrderByList {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
[LIMIT numberOfRowsToReturn]
[OFFSET numberOfRowsToSkip]
[FOR {VIEW  | REFERENCE}[,...] ]
      [ UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...] ]
```

and the [Typographical Conventions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm) (including a relevant example that uses the same syntax)

> [...] and [,...]
>
> Square brackets containing an ellipsis indicate that the preceding element can be repeated up to the limit for the element. If a comma is also present, the repeated elements must be separated by commas. If the element is a list of choices grouped with curly braces, you can use items from the list in any order. For example, in the clause `UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...]`, the `[,...]` indicates that you can use `TRACKING`, `VIEWSTAT`, or both:
>
> `UPDATE TRACKING`
>
> `UPDATE VIEWSTAT`
>
> `UPDATE TRACKING, VIEWSTAT`

This should be able to be executed as

`FOR VIEW, REFERENCE`

Unfortunately, this throws syntax errors in a v.39 org. Not sure about a v.40 org myself. Currently it looks like a few places have bad documentation around this, since the consideration to use them in conjunction is sprinkled throughout the docs for those optional clauses.

Comment: I thought I was on the right track with the SOQL syntax chart. I completely missed going through the 'typographical conventions' to decode the `[,...]`. +1 from me. I still find it strange that some incarnation of `[FOR {VIEW | REFERENCE}[,..]]` has been in the docs since v33.0, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If I read the [Typographical Conventions in This Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm)

> | - The pipe character separates alternate elements. For example, in the clause UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...], the | character indicates that you can use either TRACKING or VIEWSTAT after UPDATE.

And

> [...] and [,...] - Square brackets containing an ellipsis indicate that the preceding element can be repeated up to the limit for the element. If a comma is also present, the repeated elements must be separated by commas. If the element is a list of choices grouped with curly braces, you can use items from the list in any order. For example, in the clause UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...], the [,...] indicates that you can use TRACKING, VIEWSTAT, or both:

So, following query works for me for querying Knowledge Article using `VIEWSTAT,TRACKING` with `FOR REFERENCE`

**Valid**

```
List<Vendor_Sheet__ka> lstKav = [SELECT Id,LastViewedDate 
From Vendor_Sheet__ka WHERE Id = 'kA2q00000008UvV' 
FOR REFERENCE UPDATE VIEWSTAT,TRACKING];
System.debug('LastViewedDate=' + lstKav[0].LastViewedDate);
```

[image: Tracking SOQL]

That it also working for `FOR VIEW`

```
List<Vendor_Sheet__ka> lstKav = [SELECT Id,LastViewedDate 
From Vendor_Sheet__ka 
WHERE Id = 'kA2q00000008UvV' 
FOR VIEW UPDATE VIEWSTAT,TRACKING];
System.debug('LastViewedDate=' + lstKav[0].LastViewedDate);
```

[image: update tracking for view]

**Invalid Scenario:**

If I put wrong id (i.e. Knowledge article Id) to retrieve the Knowledge article version like this:

```
List<Vendor_Sheet__kav> lstKav = [SELECT Id From Vendor_Sheet__kav 
                                  WHERE Id='kA2q00000008UvV' 
                                  FOR VIEW UPDATE VIEWSTAT];
```

It shows me error message:

> **FOR VIEW/REFERENCE can only be used on an object where viewing is tracked**

*That's interesting !!!*

So, accordingly to me based on error message, Salesforce supports either `FOR VIEW` or `FOR REFERENCE` and not both.

The pipeline between two words clearly applicable in case of `FOR {VIEW  | REFERENCE}`

Also I am interpreting the pipe in `ORDER BY fieldOrderByList {ASC|DESC}` where same field cannot be used for both ASC and DESC.

**Invalid**

```
List<Account> acct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account 
Order By Name ASC, DESC LIMIT 2];
```

**Valid**

```
List<Account> acct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account 
Order By Name ASC, Id DESC LIMIT 2];
```